# Change a Gantt chart in amCharts so that the column values are the axis values and the old axis values are the new column values?

Tags: php, amcharts, gantt-chart

I have a Gantt chart using amCharts v3 in PHP, and we would like to swap the column values with the X-axis values. For example, we have an incident Gantt chart which have X-axis values of the locations of incidents and the columns are the staff members of a school that were attached to that location, with how many incidents they were attached to.

I have tried looking for the data that is pulled to create the chart and how they are used, but cannot see how to swap it around. Unfortunately I cannot display code as it is my company's and not mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend to upgrade to `amcharts4`, because it is much more flexible and has even new chart types. You can migrate easily, beginning with just one chart. You can use `amcharts3` and `amcharts4` in parallel ([Migration Guide](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/migrating-from-v3/)).

With `amcharts4` it is possible to swap the `xAxis` and the `yAxis`.

I used the [gantt chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/) from the amcharts demos and updatet it in a [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rPZEzg).

If you want to stay with `amcharts3` it is also possible to swap `xAxis` and `yAxis`. You just have to invert the `rotate` attribute in the config json:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "gantt",
    // your config ...
    "rotate": false,
    // more config ...
} );
```

I created another [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzXbLQ) with the full `amcharts3` example adapted from the [demo chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/gantt-chart-v3/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What i am looking for however is to switch the column data with the x-axis values. For example in your code pen, would it be possible for the x-axis to display the tasks, and then the columns to contain the people who had completed them?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible, but I think you have to adjust your data for that.